# what the purpose of maven site plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven

Does it generate javadoc site or to do with Servlet etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to produce reports and project info that can be published.
all sorts of plugins can be hooked in to the site plugin through `<reporting>`(like the source code you mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

See, for example:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/

All that content is generated with the ...

maven site plugin.